# Video rotation using mediaelement.js

Tags: rotation, mediaelement.js

I have videos uploaded directly into my web application from mobile phones.
Sometimes, depending on devices and how they hold the device, the video is rotated.

Is it possible, using mediaelement.js, to rotate the video displayed without re-encoding it?
I don't mind having the user pressing buttons to select the desired rotation.